# Vim filename autocomplete exclude files

Tags: vim

When opening another file in my project using `:e path/to/fil`<kbd>TAB</kbd>, vim will auto-complete the filename with all matching files, in alphabetical order. However, my project is full of `.coffee`, `.litcoffee`, `.js` and `.map` files.

How do I tell vim *not* to auto-complete the `.js` and `.map` files?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wildmenu is the component, if you want to call it that, responsible for the files you open with :e.
You can set ignore rules for it easily in your .vimrc using

```
set wildignore+=*.filetype
```

So say you want to ignore your filetypes, it would be:

```
set wildignore+=*.js,*.map
```

There's a great overview [here](http://blog.sanctum.geek.nz/vim-filename-completion/). I would recommend you to write a specific config file for only this project, and load it when you're working on said project. In this way, vim will only ignore these files when you want it to, and not always.

Comment: I actually had to `+=*.js,*.map` to wildignore, but thangs!

Comment: Absolutely right, typo in my example. Corrected.